# What is the difference between a bit vector and a bit string?

Tags: c++, bit, bitvector

I have to use a bit *string* in an assignment, but I've also heard bit *vector* in class, and I'm really confused on the difference. I understand how to do the assignment, but now I am not sure if I'm using the right thing. Are they the same? Can anyone explain?

Comment: By "assignment" do you mean some kind of homework?  Or do you mean you have to _assign_ it to something?  I suggest that if you mean the former, then you should provide some context about what's being asked (e.g. the description of what you're asked to do).  These terms are not really standardized.  A bit "string" might refer to a string containing the characters `'0'` and `'1'` to represent a binary number.  A bit "vector" might be a specialization of `std::vector<bool>`, or it might be an array or similar of integer types containing 0 or 1.

Comment: There is [std::bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). Which may be what is meant by bit vector.

Comment: I've never heard of a "bit string".  Are referring to ``std::string_view``?  Do you have some example code we can comment on?

Comment: Wikipedia redirects both "[bit string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_string)" and "[bit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_vector)" to "bit array", so apparently many people consider the terms to be interchangeable? (I had thought "bit string" would mean something different, but I guess I'm in the minority on that.)